# Elmah and blocking http HEAD requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah, http-head

Would there be any consequence in blocking HEAD requests with Elmah?  I get quit a few of errors that come through with Elmah.  Should I have ASP.NET MVC accept HEAD requests?  I'm not sure if I am missing something with HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this when trying to get rid of the constant errors being logged to elmah by site24x7 that is checking uptime on our asp.net mvc 3 site. using HEAD (a seemingly less heavy way of checking uptime)

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181500/respond-to-http-head-requests-using-asp-net-mvc) for how to allow HEAD requests

```
[AcceptVerbs(new[] {"GET", "HEAD"})]
public ActionResult TestMe()
{
    return View();
}
```