# Get the HTTP Method(s) for a Route name

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I want to output a list of HTTP methods that users can use for a particular route name.

E.g.

```
[HttpGet("somethingcool",Name="name"]
public IActionResult Get(){ Ok(); }

[HttpPost("somethingcool",Name="name"]
public IActionResult Post(){ Ok(); }
```

When I try to get the HTTP methods that route `name` can accept, I want to see GET, POST

Any ideas?

Comment: You should look at 'HEAD'. I think this answer could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181500/respond-to-http-head-requests-using-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @anserk HEAD is not for this. OPTIONS is.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In concept what you are asking to do isn't possible. This is because a single route can refer to any number of action methods. Naming a route is also optional. Routes are primarily designed to match the *current request*, so getting a list of all of the routes that match any possible request is not something that is built-in to routing.

But if you are using attribute routing exclusively, you could use Reflection to scan for `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` attributes in controller classes and then filter the list of attributes by the Name property.

```
var classes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetTypeInfo().IsClass && t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"));

foreach (var c in classes)
{
    var methods = c.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

     foreach (var method in methods)
     {
         var getAtt = method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(HttpGetAttribute));
         var postAtt = method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(HttpPostAttribute));

         // Check whether they are null and add metadata to your result list
     }
}
```

If you are using convention-based routing, you would need to mark methods that refer to convention-based routes with a custom attribute to indicate which route it corresponds to.

```
[RouteName("default")]
```

Then scan for that attribute similarly to how you would for `HttpGet` and `HttpPost`. But you would have to be diligent to ensure every route actually has a name and every method has one of the possible attributes to search for in order for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for this! I Managed to use `method.GetCustomAttribute<HttpMethodAttribute>(true)?.HttpMethods`

Answer (score 1):

MS provide a NuGet package to reflect on your code and find the methods your api supports. See more here: [MSDN | Creating Help Pages for ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages)

Then in you controller you can get the information from

```
Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions
```

I assume you want to expose the list of methods to clients. For this you should use OPTIONS verb which is made for exactly this purpose: [MDN | OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS)