# Add support for [HttpHead] and [HttpGet] in MVC controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-get, http-head

I have an MVC method as follows which supports the `[HttpGet]` attribute.

```
[HttpGet]        
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult IndexGet(string l)
{               
    return View();
}
```

However, I'm noticing in our web server log files we are getting a `HEAD` request, but since I don't have a `[HttpHead]` defined we are returning a 404, which is correct.  The web server log file entries are for example

> 2020-05-20 00:00:51 W3SVC1 EC2AMAZ 10.0.0.206 HEAD / 443 -
>   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX HTTP/1.1
>   Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+UptimeRobot/2.0;+http://www.uptimerobot.com/)
>   - www.domainname.com 404 0 0 306 694 155

and

> 2020-05-20 00:01:13 W3SVC1 EC2AMAZ 10.0.0.206 GET /  443 -
>   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX HTTP/1.1
>   Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+UptimeRobot/2.0;+http://www.uptimerobot.com/)
>   - www.domainname.com 200 0 0 156847 674 1065

How can I add support for `[HttpHead]` and what should I return in the response.  I tried adding both `[HttpHead]` and `[HttpGet]`

```
[HttpHead]  
[HttpGet]       
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult IndexGet(string l)
{               
    return View();
}
```

but get the following in the browser

> **The resource cannot be found.**
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

and it breaks the `[HttpGet]` method.  If I remove the `[HttpHead]` and refresh the URL the `[HttpGet]` loads fine.

Comment: Have you tried putting HttpGet _before_ HttpHead? Also, ensure that there is actually some content being returned.

Comment: @Stuart Yes, I tried both ways HttpGet then HttpHead, and also HttpHead then HttpGet.  Still the same.

Comment: HEAD should return just the headers, no content. Can you put that attribute to a new method that just returns an OK response?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing That worked thanks.  Add an answer if you wish and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A HEAD request should respond with only headers, not content. So mixing with a GET shouldn't be done.

The easiest option is to create an extra method in the controller to handle that HEAD request:

```
[HttpHead]
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult IsAlive()
{
   return Ok();
}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The HTTP spec requires responses to `HEAD` requests "be identical" to `GET` requests, except omitting the response body. The code in this answer, for example, will send an empty response which will have a different `Content-Length` header. See https://www.tpeczek.com/2017/10/exploring-head-method-behavior-in.html - A better way is to just use `[Route("...")]` and let ASP.NET Core handle `HEAD` and `GET` for you - there is no need to use `[HttpHead]` _and_ `[HttpGet]` in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpGet` or `HttpHead` attributes represents an attribute that is used to restrict an action method so that the method handles **only** HTTP GET requests or **only** HTTP HEAD requests. A request cannot be both of these so combining them causes the controller method never to match and the result is a 404 response.

The correct way to allow both GET and HEAD requests for a single controller method is to use:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Head)]
```

See the accepted answer to [Respond to HTTP HEAD requests using ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3197128)