# MVC: A public method on my controller is called OK in my development server, but not the testing server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am completely baffled by this.
I have a public method on my controller which works on my development machine. But when I deploy the app I get an error message saying the method is not found;

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, AdminIT, ManagerIT")]
    public ActionResult ListExistingIT(GridSortOptions sort, int? page)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["lastPersonMessage"] == null)
            ViewData["LastPersonMessage"] = string.Empty;
        else
            ViewData["LastPersonMessage"] = Request.QueryString["lastPersonMessage"];
        EmployeeListViewModel elvm = new EmployeeListViewModel();
        elvm.EmployeeList = EmployeeExtended.GetITEmployees();
        if (sort.Column != null)
        {
            elvm.EmployeeList = elvm.EmployeeList.OrderBy(sort.Column, sort.Direction);
        }
        elvm.EmployeeList = elvm.EmployeeList.AsPagination(page ?? 1, Utility.GetPageLength());
        ViewData["sort"] = sort;
        return View(elvm);
    }
```

The error message is; System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'ListExistingIT' was not found on controller 'SHP.Controllers.EmployeeController'.

Now you might think that IIS is not picking up the latest deployment. However I make a change elsewhere and deploy it, and that works. I also restart IIS as well.
I cannot imagine how this happens, or how to detect where the error could be.

Comment: How are you calling this action? What url are you using? What HTTP verb? Is there AJAX involved? What does FireBug say about the request?

Comment: Do you have other MVC apps that work on this server, or are other ActionResults accessible on the server?

Comment: What browser are you using, have you tried different browsers?

Comment: @BlackTigerX, browsers don't have anything to do with what he's experiencing. His issue is purely on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of discussion on a similar (the same?) issue here on SO:[Intermittent asp.net mvc exception: “A public action method ABC could not be found on controller XYZ.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745182/intermittent-asp-net-mvc-exception-a-public-action-method-abc-could-not-be-foun)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 different possibilities:

1. A conflict with the `HttpVerb`
   causing the method not to be found.
2. A conflict with the filters applied
   causing the method to be avoided.
3. A routing issue, but this one is
   probably the last possibility. You
   may want to try testing with the
   [RouteDebugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) and see what that
   shows you.