# Random get requests error in MVC application, IIS log

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, random, iis-8, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a weird problem in my MVC app. Everything works fine and the end user doesn't get affected by this but it's annoying and I am running out of ideas.

For some reason at about every hour my controller gets called with some random action name and the error gets caught in Global.asax Application_Error event. The error is following:

A public action method '..' was not found on controller '..'

To be more weird, the action names are always the same:

6, 7 and 8

I've read about this online, tried a couple of suggested solutions, like this one for example:

[Intermittent asp.net mvc exception: “A public action method ABC could not be found on controller XYZ.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745182/intermittent-asp-net-mvc-exception-a-public-action-method-abc-could-not-be-fou)

But no luck, this is not my case. The request verb is GET. Also, there are no attributes like HttpPost or HttpGet on my controller actions. (I've read that this might be the issue here)

My controller is named PostController, does that make any difference? (since there is POST verb)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks